# Parse string and subtract a substring

Tags: c, string

I'm parsing a http header in C and need to subtract host name from the full url.

I managed to get the full url (http://www.example.com/hello.html) and the path name (hello.html) but couldn't subtract (full url - path name) host name (example.com).

```
Example full url: http://www.example.com/hello.html - DONE
host name: example.com - TODO
path name: /hello.html - DONE
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You read a http header in C and do not know manipulating Strings? You should search on the net before asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`memcpy`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/memcpy.html), like this:

```
char *url = "http://www.example.com/hello.html";
// find the last index of `/`
char *path = url + strlen(url);
while (path != url && *path != '/') {
   path--;
}
// Calculate the length of the host name
int hostLen = path-url;
// Allocate an extra byte for null terminator
char *hostName = malloc(hostLen+1);
// Copy the string into the newly allocated buffer
memcpy(hostName, url, hostLen);
// Null-terminate the copied string
hostName[hostLen] = '\0';
...
// Don't forget to free malloc-ed memory
free(hostName);
```

Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/wPTXnY).

Comment: I'm getting an error saying "invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'char*'" in malloc line.

Comment: I had to cast (char *) before malloc. Thanks @dasblinkenlight.

Comment: @chatu This error means that you are compiling with a C++ compiler: standard-compliant C compilers do not require this cast.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
char Org="http://www.example.com/hello.html";
char New[200];
char Path="/hello.html";
memcpy(New,Org,strlen(Org)-strlen(Path));
New[strlen(Org)+strlen(Path)]=0;
printf("%s\n",New+12);
```